# How to calculate percentage in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to calculate percentage of the given long value.
The following code is returning zero .
How to calculate percentage in c#

```
long value = (fsize / tsize) * (long)100;
```

Here fsize and tsize is some Long values.

Comment: what are the values of fsize and tsize? what types are they? when you set breakpoints and debug, what happens?

Comment: I believe all your operands are int/long type and you are doing integer arithmetic.

Comment: Are `fsize` and `tsize` integers, then this is an integer divison which results also in an int-value.

Comment: Not a very good duplicate target.  The problem is more about data types and not actually about how to calculate a percentage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
var value = ((double)fsize / tsize) * 100;
var percentage = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(value, 0));
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

```
double value = ((double)fsize / (double)tsize) * 100.0;
```

if `fsize` is `int` and `tsize` is `int` then the division is also an `int` and 0 is the correct answer. You need to convert it to `double` to get the correct value back.

Answer (score 2):

best way to do this

```
int percentage = (int)Math.Round(((double)current / (double)total) * 100);
```